# Lightning component flow custom validation error message

Tags: lightning-aura-components, validation, visual-workflow

I'm following the instructions here to create custom validation for a Lightning Component in my Flow:

[Available For Flow Screens](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:availableForFlowScreens/documentation)

> Custom Validation
>
> Salesforce validates each flow screen when the user attempts to
>   navigate to the next screen. If the flow screen is not valid, the user
>   can’t progress. To validate the component with the flow screen,
>   declare the validate attribute in the component. Set the validate
>   attribute to a custom validation function that must return two
>   parameters: isValid and errorMessage.

The validation works, and the error message is displayed, but its at the very bottom of the component.  Is there a way I can control placement of the error message, like to somewhere closer to the top of the component?  Right now it displays after my custom component and the footer button bar:

[image]

Comment: Were you able to control placement of the error message (Maybe show to the top of the component)

Answer (score 2):

I wound up hiding the Flow footer and creating my own [Next] button.  Clicking the [Next] button triggers JS controller code that validates the input.

Comment: But then how do you progress the flow, or close the modal?

Comment: It's possible to dispatch Flow-specific events with both aura and LWC, @wizulus. [Aura documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_flow_screens_navigate.htm) & [LWC wtih lightning-flow-support module](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-flow-support/documentation)

Comment: @nbrown that's what I did.  I followed the material "Customize the Flow Footer with an Aura Component" section.